# How to POST data to webserver before Mechanical Turk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, python-requests, mechanicalturk

I am currently doing the following in Mechanical Turk for an external question:

```
<form name="mturk" method="post" action="https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit">
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Text: <input type="text" name="text"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="assignmentId" value="3AZHRG4CU4K686LQ1BGIRZZETDV03F">
    <input type="submit" name="form-submission" value="Elephant">
</form>
```

It works, if I submit that form.

However instead of doing the above, I would like to `POST` to my webserver, do all the validation, and then `POST` to Mechanical Turk. Something like:

```
import requests
url='https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/externalSubmit'
data={'name': 'david', 'text': 'mark', 'assignmentId': '3AZHRG4CU4K686LQ1BGIRZZETDV03F'}
r=requests.post(url, data=data)
r.text
```

---

**There was a problem submitting your results for this HIT.**

\n\n\t

This HIT is still assigned to you.  To try this HIT again, click "HITs Assigned To You" in the navigation bar, then click "Continue work on this HIT" for the HIT.  If this problem persists, you can contact the Requester for this HIT using the "Contact" link above.

\n\n\t

To return this HIT and continue working on other HITs, click the "Return HIT" button.

\n

---

Why is this occurring when I do a `POST` using requests? How should I be doing this?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? It seems like faking a header will not work as cookies got involved. Is it possible to submit 1 form to 2 domains by javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're encountering the same issue [described here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=553442). Basically, MTurk apparently blocks these kind of requests that don't come in the form of a browser redirect. If I understand the AWS response on that thread correctly, there's nothing you can do about this.

Comment: Thanks again for this link. So, in the case of gathering data, the way to go is to do something like a `cron` job by getting the assignments for that HIT (`conn.get_assignments(hit_id=hit_id)`), and then from that populating my database?

Comment: @David542 Yes, or use [the Notifications API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_NotificationReceptorAPIArticle.html) to trigger `GetAssignment` API calls from your server.